# How Spacy NER verifies the rationality of entities?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

When I use SpaCy NER, SpaCy will recognize 'TodoA' as PERSON. This is obviously unreasonable. Is there any way to verify whether the entity extracted by SpaCy is reasonable? Thanks!

Most of these unreasonable entities are extracted by spacy beam search. The beam search code is:

```
import spacy
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

nlp = spacy.load('en')
text = u'Will Japan join the European Union? If yes, we should \ 
move to United States. Fasten your belts, America we are coming'


with nlp.disable_pipes('ner'):
    doc = nlp(text)

threshold = 0.2
(beams, somethingelse) = nlp.entity.beam_parse([ doc ], beam_width = 16, beam_density = 0.0001)

entity_scores = defaultdict(float)
for beam in beams:
    for score, ents in nlp.entity.moves.get_beam_parses(beam):
        for start, end, label in ents:
            entity_scores[(start, end, label)] += score

print ('Entities and scores (detected with beam search)')
for key in entity_scores:
    start, end, label = key
    score = entity_scores[key]
    if ( score > threshold):
        print ('Label: {}, Text: {}, Score: {}'.format(label, doc[start:end], score))
```

Comment: SpaCy has neural network underneath that processes feature attributes for supervised learning. If you're interested in what features are used, certainty of assignment, or multiclass probabilities it's unclear from your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Hi @SergeyBushmanov It has nothing to do with the underlying neural network. I just used the pre-trained model en_core_web_lg in spacy for entity extraction, and used beam_search. When a sentence contains 'TodoA', spacy en_core_web_lg will recognize 'TodoA' as a person, and 'TodoA' is obviously not a person's name , So the spacy en_core_web_lg identification error, what I want to do now is to judge the rationality of the entity extracted by spacy en_core_web_lg

Answer (score 2):

The "*unreasonable*" annotation you are seeing is directly linked with the nature of the model that is used to perform the annotation and the process of obtaining it.

In short, the model is an **approximation** of a very complex function (in mathematical terms) from some characteristics of sequences of words (e.g. presence of particular letters, upper-casing, usage of particular terms, etc.) to a closed set of tags (e.g. `PERSON`). It is an approximation that is close to best across a large body of text (e.g. a few GBs of ASCII text) but certainly it is not a mapping of particular phrases to tags. Therefore, even though the data which is used for training is accurate, the result of applying the model might be not ideal in some circumstances.

In your case it is likely that the model is clinging on upper-casing of a word, and maybe there was a large number of words used in training that share the prefix that were marked with tag `PERSON`) - e.g. Toddy, toddler, etc. and a very small number of words with such a prefix that were not `PERSON`s.

This phenomenon that we observe was not chosen explicitly by person preparing the model, it is only a by-product of the combination of the process of preparing it (training), and the data used.

Comment: So spacy itself cannot solve this problem. After spacy extracts the entity, is there any way to verify whether the entity extracted by spacy is reasonable?

Comment: As @sophros has pointed out, the machine learns what it learns. Of course, this will get better in years to come, but for now, the model does what it does and performs well _in_general_. This is the goal of machine learning. If you feel that you can add heuristics to improve the results, then that will need to be done after the ML has applied it's learning.